# Narrowing typescript generic type based on discriminated unions

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have some type definitions as shown below.

```js
type PayloadType = 'A' | 'B';

interface Payload<T extends PayloadType> {
  type: T;
}

interface PayloadA extends Payload<'A'> {
  state: string
}

interface PayloadB extends Payload<'B'> {
  serialNumber: string;
}

type TPayload = PayloadA | PayloadB;


type PayloadInterpretation<T extends TPayload> = {
  payload: T;
  entries: T[]; // This property is only for demonstration purpose
};

type TPayloadInterpretation = PayloadInterpretation<PayloadA> | PayloadInterpretation<PayloadB>;

function f(interpretation: TPayloadInterpretation) {
  if (interpretation.payload.type === 'B') {
    const payload = interpretation.payload; // payload is of type PayloadB
    const entries = interpretation.entries; // entries is of type PayloadA[] | PayloadB[]
  }
}
```

The comments show that even the type of payload can be correctly narrowed down to `PayloadB` based on discriminated unions, but the type `T[]` for `entries` is still `PayloadA[] | PayloadB[]`.

I was thinking if typescript knows the type `T` for payload is `PayloadA`, it should also be able to narrow `entries: T[]` to `entries: PayloadB[]`. I know I could do a type casting like:

```js
function f(interpretation: TPayloadInterpretation) {
  if (interpretation.payload.type === 'B') {
    const payloadBInterpretation = interpretation as PayloadInterpretation<PayloadB>;
    ...
  }
}
```

But my question would be is there any other way to do this?

The code is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEwCrmgXigcgEF8oAfAgIXwG4AoWgSwDtgIAnAMzgGNp4lUaADwYoEAB6smaAM6wEKdFkgA%20KAG9aUKKEgAuKBjoBfes1acefBYMJjJEaXP6LhRfGs3aZwOKwM%20bMwA5rSmjCzsXLzyAugU9lKysa5C%20FSeWlAy7AxwiAByAK4AtgBG7AHAQUzBJvS60BguglB4Leh25B1oFHQN2CmCAJKRbGBsEL7ADMhMIomOyc026Gp4XlBgq2gGRlmO1QwQMnsA2gC61FAA9DeGABYMchPIkGygUM9Qc4ggUBxkGwoGgICU5oE-LMmFsiuNkDkwv1GoYeqMLBMplC5m0huh0exMdNoUIeoQ1N0dgTxpNiXNSTsKCp%20hwikxuDMcRwABTmQm07FMPZosZEwUASg0WQYHCgvNFAs5TAAdNs4mhlSicNrKPhJZttNwIcAtjtcXyaVilaqdtc7qb1V85MhZSiehQsobjWIWEETuaFVbocrDn6ZHb7qHjnJvi6dIMyZcyHjepdPVAjUwfA7XBRqWKlQGMYroVA4M4qYG6fN3cz05ns2rXAAmXFNwR5quCm3qiM51qx10Jxn171Rk6tvDt%20L5ktzEO%206N98cx51DyApihp7SmcJAA) in typescript playground.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check for `interpretation.payload.type`, you are only narrowing the `interpretation.payload` object. You are not actually doing anything to narrow `interpretation.entries`.

In other words, typescript doesn't know that `interpretation.entries` can also be narrowed when you narrow `interpretation.payload`.

If you want both of them to be narrowed, you need another discriminator in the `PayloadInterpretation` type:

```
// ...

type PayloadInterpretation<T extends TPayload> = {
  type: T['type']; // the new discriminator for the whole PayloadInterpretation
  payload: T;
  entries: T[];
};

// ...

function f(interpretation: TPayloadInterpretation) {
  if (interpretation.type === 'B') { // narrowing the whole interpretation instead of only interpretation.payload
    const payload = interpretation.payload; // payload is of type PayloadB
    const entries = interpretation.entries; // entries is of type PayloadB[]
  }
}
```